# jQuery many of the same elements, one has to start when you click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code like that:

```
<img src="fl_uk.png" class="menulink" />
<div class="test">Something</div>
<img src="fl_uk.png" class="menulink" />
<div class="test">Something2</div>





$('.menulink').click(function(){
    if($('.menulink').attr('src') == "fl_pol.png"){
        $(this).attr('src',"fl_uk.png");
        $('.test').hide('slow');
        return false;
    }   
    else
    {
        $(this).attr('src',"fl_pol.png");
        $('.test').show('slow');
        return false;
    }


});
```

When I clicking on img should change image and show div. When I click again image should back to first and div should hide. That's working fine. But I woul like to do that should be there many imgae-buttons and many divs and after clicking one image-button should only change this image and open div below image. I don't know how many his image and div will be because they are generating from database.
How to create jQuery code to not repeat jQuery code

Comment: This kind of question demonstrates one of the reasons I hate jQuery. It makes me want to ask "how in the world do you expect this to possible work???"...

Comment: you may want to give a relationship flag between the images and the divs. then it'll be much easier and safer.

Comment: @domos: Ask yourself, how you would define a style specifically for one menu item? You can't because they are identical and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @Kolink: jQuery is great when it is used by a software engineer and someone who is skilled with javascript. The "good" thing with jQuery is, it can also be used without javascript or software engineering skills, and that's why you hate jQuery :-)

Comment: @TJ. Yeah, that's probably it. You've hit the nail on the head with that one.

Answer (score 1):

I might have done this like :

```
<img src="fl_uk.png" rel="uk" class="menulink" />
<div class="test" rel="uk_div">Something</div>
<img src="fl_pol.png" rel="pol" class="menulink" />
<div class="test" rel="pol_div">Something2</div>
```

and then

```
$(".menulink").on("click",function(){
    $(".test").hide();
    $("div[rel='"+$(this).attr("rel") + "_div']").show());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I'm going to assume you have a container around those images, such as `<div id="images">...</div>`. Now the solution is really simple:

```
document.getElementById('images').onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = e.currentSrc || e.target;
    if( !t.tagName) t = t.parentNode;
    while( t != this && t.tagName != "IMG") t = t.parentNode;
    if( t != this) {
        if( t.src == "fl_pol.png") {
            t.src = "fl_uk.png";
            t.nextSibling.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            t.src = "fl_pol.png";
            t.nextSibling.style.display = "";
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

This is done in raw JS, rather than jQuery, which means it's considerably faster. It also delegates the event so there's only one listener, rather than one per image.

Comment: Do you hate jQuery >.< I can feel you :)

Comment: Yes, I hate it about as much as I hate poetry... >_>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.menulink').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).attr('src') == "fl_pol.png"){
    $(this).attr('src',"fl_uk.png");
    $(this).next('.test').hide('slow');
    return false;
  }else{
    $(this).attr('src',"fl_pol.png");
    $(this).next('.test').show('slow');
    return false;
  }
});
```